# Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS - no password prompt

Tags: server

I cannot log into my server.

I cannot SSH into the server; PuTTY fails with the message "Server unexpectedly closed network connection" if I am outside my own network, or "Software caused connection abort" if I am inside my network.

So I plugged a monitor and keyboard into it and got a login prompt.  But when I enter my user name and press enter, I am not given a password prompt.  It sits for a moment, then the screen goes black, and when I tap a key to wake it up I have a fresh login prompt.

I could reboot the server but I'm mildly leery of doing so.  I recently cloned an existing installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS over to a new hard drive (changing to SSD), and it worked, so I also upgraded to 18.04.1.  That went well also; but then shortly afterwards I had to reboot it and it died with the error "error: invalid arch independent ELF magic", indicating that something was screwed up with the MBR.

The hardware is old; it's not compatible with the amd64 instruction set, only i386, and they stopped making live CDs for i386.  So in order to fix it I had to download a 16.04 live CD and correct the MBR issue (and also run a fsck which found and corrected errors on two partitions).

This sucker was rock solid for *years* before I put this SSD in it.  I'm annoyed that a simple hard drive swap has caused me such grief.

Any suggestions?  How do I log in when I can't get a password prompt?

Comment: Note: they still make installer images for i386, but just the Network installer type, not the Live installer type.

Comment: Correct. Which, sadly, didn't help in my case, since the live version is what I needed.

Comment: I gave up and tried rebooting.  It's definitely something with the hard drive -- it failed to unmount any of the file systems during power off, and I got a kernel panic when I tried booting again.  ARGH.  What is messing with the file system?

Comment: After failing to correct the issue -- a fsck found thousands upon thousands of errors in two of my partitions -- I gave up.  Either the hard drive is a lemon, there's a hardware incompatibility between the SATA3 drive in a SATA2 port, or there's some weird bug in 18.04 LTS that affects my specific hardware.  I have restored the old HD that still had 16.04 on it, and it's working fine now.